# How to document.write( ) on a click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show QR code onclick or onmousehover over a button "Show QR Code".

I also want to insure that the javascript of http://www.qrsrc.com which generate and display the QR code Renders/Shows QR code only when "Show QR Code" button is clicked or hovered over with mouse.
Below is the script i used for that but it does not work. can anyone tell me what is wrong with this script.

This is a encoded script for Blogger:-

```
&lt;button onclick=&quot;function () {
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;http://www.qrsrc.com/qrcode.js?url=http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=<data:post.title/>&amp;id=<data:post.id/>\&quot; id='qrsrc' &gt; &lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);}&quot;&gt;Show QR Code&lt;/button&gt;
```

This is a converted script after page go live:-

```
<button onclick="function () {
document.write("<script src=\"http://www.qrsrc.com/qrcode.js?url=http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android&id=3384228222355572267\" id='qrsrc' > <\/script>");}">Show QR Code</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to display a qr code as image:

```
<button onclick="
var height=100;
var width=100;
var urltoencode = 'http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android';
document.getElementById('qr').src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs='+width+'x'+height+'&chl='+escape(urltoencode);"
>Show QR Code</button>
<img id="qr">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nB6R/)

or the same with jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="
var height=100;
var width=100;
var urltoencode = 'http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android';
$('#qr').attr('src', 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs='+width+'x'+height+'&chl='+escape(urltoencode));"
>Show QR Code</button>
<img id="qr">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxKwf/)

This creates a button and a hidden image in HTML.
The script defines the height, width and the "to be encoded" variable and finds the hidden image which source will be set to a qr code (google api)

And Finally, on hover over (+ fancy fade):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<button style="float: left;" id="qrButton">Show QR Code</button>
<img id="qr">
<script>
var height=100;
var width=100;
var urltoencode = 'http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android';
$('#qr').attr('src', 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs='+width+'x'+height+'&chl='+escape(urltoencode)).hide();
$('#qrButton').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#qr').fadeIn("slow");
});
$('#qrButton').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#qr').fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4g6L/)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `function () {` from the `onclick` attribute and '}' at the end.
when you set a event attribute inline, you provide the code itself and the JavaScript would wrap your code in a function. so you just do this:

```
<button onclick="document.write('<script src=\"http://www.qrsrc.com/qrcode.js?url=http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android&id=3384228222355572267\" id=\"qrsrc\" ><\/script>');">Show QR Code</button>
```

although you better not use `document.write` because, it wipes out all the other tags you have in page.

but if you insist on using function you can do this:

```
<button onclick="(function(){ document.write('<script src=\"http://www.qrsrc.com/qrcode.js?url=http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android&id=3384228222355572267\" id=\"qrsrc\" ><\/script>'); })();">Show QR Code</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't allow `document.write` to work, because its security problem. In XHTML, it also doesn't work. `document.write` removes all other contents from that page on call, so it's bad practice, don't use it. Use `element.innerHTML` or `element.appendChild` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you have jQuery, do this instead:

```
<button onclick='$(this).after(
         $("<script src=\"http://www.qrsrc.com/qrcode.js?url=http://search.google.androidappania.com/?q=Download WebMD Full Apk for Android&id=3384228222355572267\" id=\"qrsrc\" />")
    );'>Show QR Code</button>
```